# Разделить атрибут картинки на две части и назначить переменную. jQuery

Tags: jquery

Есть код, который заменяет картинку на другую.

```
HTML:
   <div id="pic">
    <img width="50" src="https://name_1.jpeg">
    </div> 
jQuery:
  $('#pic img') // Ищем IMG в родителе
  .eq(0) // Берём первую картинку 
  .attr('src', 'https://name_2.jpeg'); // Меняем значение атрибута SRC на своё
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как назначить "name_2.jpeg" через переменную. Я пытаюсь сделать что-то вроде этого:

```
jQuery:
  $('#pic img') // Ищем IMG в родителе
  .eq(0) // Берём первую картинку 
  .attr('src', 'https://' + 'name_jpeg ');
  name_jpeg = 'name_2.jpeg';
```

Извините меня, если я неправильно указал термины.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так:

```
let name_jpeg = 'name_2.jpeg';

.......attr('src', 'https://' + name_jpeg );
```

или

```
let name_jpeg = 'name_2.jpeg';

.......attr('src', `https://${name_jpeg}`);
                // ^--обратная кавчка   ^--обратная кавычка
```